# Windows Firewall blocking everything when authenticating against domain

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, domain, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to run Microsoft's platform ready tests on my company's applications, which for the gold certification requires that we install our application on Server 2012 R2 Core. I have got a Hyper-V VM running Server 2012 R2 Core with all our prereqs installed, with the test program running no problem.

Part of our install includes entering credentials to use as a service account. It seems that the moment I enter domain credentials in there, the VM loses all network connectivity until I reboot it. The only way I'm able to access it (without rebooting) is to console in via Hyper-V manager.

After testing, it seems that Windows Firewall is deciding to block network connectivity when our installer does the authentication, because if I disable Windows Firewall after this happens I get network again. The problem is MPR requires that Windows Firewall stay enabled at all times during the test.

How can I diagnose what is causing Windows Firewall to do this, or at least work around this?